# Simple GUI IDE?

Tags: c++, linux, ide

I'm looking for a GUI Linux IDE.

Specs:

- **simple** and fool proof. normal look & feel
- full as-you-type indentation in most languages
- a compile+run button, a debugger, auto-refactoring for C++
- basic unintrusive support for common buildsystems - straight make, cmake, qmake, autotools
- smooth workflow. proper keyboard support, no jarring transitions between debugging/coding modes, etc

What i've tried:

- KDevelop is bloated and buggy, makes it difficult to even transfer projects between machines etc
- jEdit is ugly, feature poor and it's difficult to find things. but it does indentation well.
- Anjuta, Geany and a bunch of other micro-IDEs for GNOME fail at indentation and misc features
- Code::Blocks only does C++, it's pretty complex and it can be hard to get things working with libs etc
- vi and e-macs are nice but I'm not taking the time to learn them right now, and I want something coworkers can use as well
- NetBeans has a terrible Swing look, weird code editor. also it's pretty slow and seems complicated. great features though.
- Eclipse. pretty huge and complex, I don't like the UI. I feel like I can't do anything without a tutorial

Presently I use KDevelop for work and gedit+terminal for hobby dev, but wanted to see if I'm missing out.

Comment: If you find Code::Blocks complex, then there is no IDE that I can suggest.

Answer (score 8):

You could try [QtCreator](http://www.qtsoftware.com/products/appdev/developer-tools/developer-tools). It's not quite complete (as of this this posting at least), but it might be closer to what you want than some of the others you've tried. It's very keyboard friendly.

Answer (score 1):

I tried [PIDA](http://pida.co.uk/) after [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python/81629#81629), and I think it's pretty good. You'd still have to learn vi/emacs to use it, though.

I'd also suggest you take a look at [MonoDevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/). It's basically M$ Visual Studio for Linux, and it has all the features you listed.

Answer (score 0):

maybe just try kate. it's a great editor with plenty of plugins, ability to use built in terminal, code folding, and it fits nice in kde desktop. Plus it's very fast.

Comment: erm, kate cant compile, run, debug, or refactor programs.. did you even read my post